# Cloud Storage getImageServingUrl using NodeJS App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to generate public image URLS using NodeJS AppEngine and I want to be able to use the `getImageServingUrl()` function that [PHP App Engine offers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.cloud_storage.CloudStorageTools).

I know this isn't available in NodeJS but is there an endpoint I can hit instead to get this to work using curl or something?

I really don't want to have to write a whole new App Engine service just to get the serving url for an image.